# in Excel is it possible to use a standard function in place of a lambda?

Tags: excel, lambda, built-in

When making templates in excel with indeterminate table sizes I like to use array functions

one fairly simple task I like to implement is row/column total so SUM seems like an appropriate tool, but SUM is a greedy function and will consume an array of any shape and collapse it into a cell.

Lambda functions to the rescue, `BYROW` sounds like it can do what I want, however defining the LAMBDA every time or using name manager feels awkward, especially when it is to alias a predefined function

using BYROW / BYCOL:

```
CODE A:
=BYROW (myArray, LAMBDA (row, SUM (Row))
```

and if I use *Name Manager*, I can simplify the statement to

```
CODE B:
mySum :=  LAMBDA (row, SUM (Row))
=BYROW (myArray, mySum)
```

However when I try (below) I get a #NAME error.

```
CODE C:
=BYROW (myArray, SUM)
```

Is there a way to tell excel to check the default functions e.g. or is this the best options that I have is to use *Name Manager*

as an aside:
Is Code A the best way for single use, and Code B optimal for reuse in workbook, or is there a simpler implementation that can be used to achieve the row/column subtotal.

Comment: What is and what is not optimal is a personal preference.  I personally do not like storing formula as a Name, because it makes it harder to trouble shoot and track.  I always go with A.  But to your larger question: No, Lambda must be used.  There are many formula that are designed around its abilities.  And without it the formula will not work.

Comment: Don't know if it's still relevant, but now it can be done with the beta version of Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible yet (March 2024), but it will be soon!

Check out this [Microsoft Blog post about upcoming `GROUPBY` and `PIVOTBY` functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/new-aggregation-functions-groupby-and-pivotby/ba-p/3965765) (currently in beta versions).

As part of implementing these functions, they've discuss **Functions as Arguments** - basically using `LAMBDA` functions. Many existing functions like `SUM`, `AVERAGE`, `MAX` and `MIN` can simply be selected from a list:
[image: Selecting SUM from a dropdown list of summary functions]

**Plus** they've added this functionality to all the existing functions that currently use `LAMBDA`s!
[image: Demonstrating using functions as arguments]

I'm very excited to see this roll out to general availability. But in the meantime, your approach of defining a simple lambda for sum, (and count, max, min...) is probably the best way to go.
I've gone with an "L." prefix (for lambda) myself:

```
L.Sum    = LAMBDA(x, sum(x));
L.Max    = LAMBDA(x, max(x));
L.Min    = LAMBDA(x, min(x));
L.Count  = LAMBDA(x, count(x));
L.CountA = LAMBDA(x, counta(x));
```

### Function Currying

Lastly, there is an approach referred to as function 'currying', which I've read about (but not experienced in). It's where you have a function that returns a *function* as a result. So it would be possible to write just a single function that depending on the parameters you pass would be equivalent to a `sum(x)` or `count(x)` function, or even `textjoin(",", x)` or `textjoin("|", x)`. While I don't have an implementation completed, you could imagine a large `IFS` block. Then you could use it like this:

```
=BYCOL(A2:F9, Summary("sum"))
=BYCOL(A2:F9, Summary("count"))
=BYCOL(A2:F9, Summary("max"))
=BYCOL(A2:F9, Summary("textjoin",","))
=BYCOL(A2:F9, Summary("textjoin","|"))
```

Now all you have to do is write the function...!

```
Summary = lambda(func,[optparam], 
  lambda(x,
    ifs(
      func="sum",sum(x),
      func="max",max(x),
      func="min",min(x),
      func="count",count(x),
      func="textjoin",textjoin(optparam,true,x),
      "else"="else",NA()
    )
  )
);
```

And **it works!!!**

[image: A function currying with Excel Lambda functions]

This [FlexYourData post](https://www.flexyourdata.com/blog/excel-lambda-simplified-rolling-aggregate-of-any-function/) may be the only reference online to function currying in Excel. Well, was - this may be the second. :-)